# How to automatically update table when values are added in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

**vacation_days**:

```
id    name     work_days      hire
-------------------------------------
 1    John        369       20151226
 2    Mike        767       20141123
 3    Josh       1166       20131020
```

There is a formula to get hire:

```
UPDATE vacation_days SET work_days = DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DATE(hire))
```

However if I add a new row I get null values:

```
id    name     work_days      hire
-------------------------------------
 1    John        369       20151226
 2    Mike        767       20141123
 3    Josh       1166       20131020 
 4    Richard    NULL       20120623
```

I have tried to use a trigger like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER onInsert BEFORE INSERT ON vacation_days
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.work_days = DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DATE(hire))
END;
```

However I get an error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
 your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
 ''vacation_days' FOR EACH ROW SET work_days = DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE
 (NEW.hire))' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't update! Just use a view:

```
create view v_vacation_days 
    select vd.*, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(vd.hire)) as workdays
    from vacation_days vd;
```

Then the value will be up-to-date whenever you query the view.

Note:  You need to remove `workdays` from the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using Insert Before, But the Hire data is not available until inserted, so you can not get the Hire date for the calculations. You want to indicate `NEW` or `OLD` Hire data for the usage.

Use this following Insert Before Trigger for your usage,

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER vacation_days_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT
   ON vacation_days FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   -- Insert record into table
   INSERT INTO vacation_days 
   ( id,
     name,
     work_days,
     hire)
   VALUES
   ( NEW.id,
     NEW.name,
     DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),DATE(NEW.hire)),
     NEW.hire );

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```